# How does Wicket's AjaxFallbackOrderByBorder work?

Tags: java, wicket

I'm using Wicket's `OrderByBorder` for sorting. It's working fine, but it refreshes my page. I want to use `AjaxFallbackOrderByBorder` instead; how can I do this? Here's my current code:

```
datacontainer.add(new OrderByBorder("orderByKeywordName", "keywordName",
 kewordSortable) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onSortChanged() {
        dataView.setCurrentPage(0);
    }
}).setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most Wicket AJAX components are designed so that you can use them to replace the non-AJAX versions by simply dropping them in. `AjaxFallbackOrderByBorder` doesn't seem to be an exception. So, you should be able to simply use

```
datacontainer.add(new AjaxFallbackOrderByBorder("orderByKeywordName",
  "keywordName", kewordSortable) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void onSortChanged() {
        dataView.setCurrentPage(0);
    }
}).setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

If you look at the Javadoc ([AJAX](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/repeater/data/sort/AjaxFallbackOrderByBorder.html), [non-AJAX](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/sort/OrderByBorder.html)), you'll see the relevant signatures are identical.

Also, it won't affect compilation or anything, but you misspelled "keyword" in `kewordSortable`.